# warble config error for Redmine 3.3, ruby 2.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I installed warbler gem to package rails applications as Java web application .war files.

but i got error after type command:

`warble config`

Here is the error message:

```
/home/run/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x117d47c warbler-2.0.3> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/run/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
    from /home/run/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warbler-2.0.3/bin/warble:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/warble:23:in `load'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/warble:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Thx for Tom Lord.  After updating gem, the "warble config" was ok.
But when i type :

```
warble
```

I got another error:

```
 [run@localhost redmine-3.3]$ gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
[run@localhost redmine-3.3]$ warble 
/home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: key "inodot" is duplicated and overwritten on line 466
application directory `lang' does not exist or is not a directory; skipping
warble aborted!
/home/run/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/errors.rb:41:in `build_message': undefined method `size' for #<Bundler::SpecSet:0x0000000240beb8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/run/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/errors.rb:34:in `message'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:224:in `display_exception_message_details'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:211:in `display_exception_details'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:200:in `display_error_message'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:187:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warbler-2.0.3/lib/warbler/application.rb:79:in `run'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warbler-2.0.3/lib/warbler/application.rb:74:in `run'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warbler-2.0.3/bin/warble:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/warble:23:in `load'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/warble:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/run/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It looks like there was a [bug](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1420) reported a while ago, which has been fixed. Try running `gem update --system` to update rubygems. If this issue is happening within a specific bundle, then try: `bundle clean; gem install executable-hooks`.

Comment: Also, by the way, ruby `2.3.3` hasn't been released yet; looking at the stack trace, you're using `2.3.0`. You may want to fix that title :)